# Custom dropdown menu wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, menu

I need to make custom wordpress menu which must look like this :  http://postimg.org/image/58na9x6jn/
I made some custom css code and now my menu looks like this http://postimg.org/image/r6jr3plk3/

Link to website is http://121.41.110.134/leibniz

Can somebody tell me how to modify css to get desired look.

Comment: can you post your code or create a simplified jsfiddle for us?

Comment: CSS :  http://pastebin.com/qEQ8SFnd
i used default wordpress menu